# zxing C# performance slow when no barcode

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing

I use a barcode for a scanning application. All scanned pages need to be checked for a barcode. As the barcode is always in the same spot i can crop the area to speed up the process a bit. The problem is, that only some of the scanned pages have the barcode in it. Others don't have one.

- Search for barcode on a page with barcode is around 1-3 seconds.
- Search for barcode on a page without a barcode is arount 10s

Now the barcodes should be easy to find on the ones that have one, as those pages only contain this Code128 and are a plain white paper otherwise. Is there any options that I could set to speed up the process?
TryHarder-Flag is already set to false, btw.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I am not sure the C# version is very optimized... that sounds really slow compared to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your library is looking through the entire image for the barcode and when there is none, it takes a lot of time - because it goes through the entire image (linear complexity). On the other hand, if it finds one (and it should a few rows/columns down) - it might use one or more horizontal lines to extract the barcode data which makes it pretty fast in those cases.

To speed up your app, I would recommend that you first try to detect the barcode yourself and if detected, pass it to zxing. You can do this by checking pixel values along the middle row of the image and if you find no "like black" pixels, assume there is no barcode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: TryHarder-Flag is already set to false is not how you do it! It just checks if there is anything set on that flag! If you don't set it at all, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution provided by ananthonline, you can try the following method to speed up the process:

1. Crop the area as you've already done.
2. Since the pages only contain Code128, you can specify the barcode type in your code. otherwise, zxing will check and verify all the supported barcode types, and it will slow down the performance a lot.